# How can i open a link in my webbrowser application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

[image: b]
[image]
Hi i want to do like this. i'm writing a  webbrowser application in c# and i will set as default browser.but i have one problem if i set it won't open clicked link from other program or html file on desktop.
how can i do that ? 
it should be like this photos.
i hope you understand my english.sorry for my english. :)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel3.BackColor = Doga_Rhodonit.Properties.Settings.Default.themebg;

        ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(what should i write or what event should i write??);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your  browser is set to the default when a link is pressed the OS will send the URL as a argument

```
   string URL = null;

   public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            URL = args[0];
        }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel3.BackColor = Doga_Rhodonit.Properties.Settings.Default.themebg;

        ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(URL);
```

Comment: how can i catch url ...   string URL = null;

   public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            URL = args[0];
        }

???with this??? :)

Comment: I don't understand ... you assign it from the args passed URL = args[0]; is what your looking for

Comment: i want catch requested url from outside.then my application will open requested url.

Comment: URL = args[0] will do the trick as long as you have it in main

Comment: Environment.GetCommandLineArgs  Will also get you the array you are looking for